# Is there a way to keep track of all changes in a SharePoint site collection?

Tags: alert, site-collection

My company is soon rolling out a SharePoint-based intranet.

During the first few weeks of the rollout I would like to keep close track of all the content that is added and edited on the sites.

Is there a simple way to keep track of all changes made in a site collection? Ideally I would like to see a list of all changes made to everything that I have access to. For instance: list items added/edited, notes added/edited

I am aware of the 'Alerts' functionality, but AFAIK I can only add alerts for individual lists/document libraries etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup **Audit Logging** in SharePoint 2010 to accomplish this. Visit [this blog](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/) to see how this is accomplished.

Check out [the office site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx) to see what all features are captured in Audit logging.

Comment: blog post updated to: http://davecoleman146.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/